# Android Google maps: How to use TileProvider with images from assets folder

Tags: android, google-maps

I wrote the code below, the full path using Android Assets folder. But the tile provider cannot find the image, so the Map stays empty without any tile shown.
If anyone can assist with this issue?

```
private TileOverlay mTiles;
private String MAP_URL_FORMAT = "file:///android_asset/%d/x%d_y%d.png";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tile_overlay);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
            (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    LatLng supperland = new LatLng(31.978574, 34.744219);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(supperland, 9));


    TileProvider tileProvider = new UrlTileProvider(256, 256) {
        @Override
        public synchronized URL getTileUrl(int x, int y, int zoom) {

            String s = String.format(Locale.US, MAP_URL_FORMAT, zoom, x, y);
            URL url = null;

                    try {
                        url = new URL(s);
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        throw new AssertionError(e);
                    }

            return url;
        }
    };

    mTiles = map.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(tileProvider));
}
```

Comment: Someone told me to use the non absolute path, but seems that for Android Assets folder this is teh correct path that I found, is this correct???

Comment: Wouldn't it use too much space when including all tiles of the world in the apk?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private TileOverlay mTiles;
    private AppCompatActivity mThis;
    private String MAP_URL_FORMAT = "%d/x%d_y%d.png";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mThis = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.tile_overlay);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        LatLng supperland = new LatLng(31.978574, 34.744219);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(supperland, 9));

        TileProvider tileProvider = new TileProvider() {

            int width = 256; //width;
            int height = 256; //height;

            @Override
            public Tile getTile(int x, int y, int zoom) {
                String path = String.format(Locale.US, MAP_URL_FORMAT, zoom, x, y);

                if(path == null) {
                    return NO_TILE;
                } else {
                    Tile tile;
                    try {
                        InputStream is = mThis.getAssets().open(path);
                        tile = new Tile(width, height, streamToBytes(is));
                    } catch (IOException var7) {
                        tile = null;
                    }

                    return tile;
                }
            }

            private byte[] streamToBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                read(inputStream, byteArrayOutputStream);
                return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
            }

            private long read(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
                byte[] var2 = new byte[4096];
                long var3 = 0L;

                while(true) {
                    int var5 = inputStream.read(var2);
                    if(var5 == -1) {
                        return var3;
                    }

                    outputStream.write(var2, 0, var5);
                    var3 += (long)var5;
                }
            }
        };

        mTiles = map.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(tileProvider));
    }
}
```